# Error using Numba to improve performance: non-constant value

Tags: python-3.x, performance, numba

I wrote a function for the tridiagonal matrix solver (using Thomas algorithm) _ Adapted form Mike "HoneyChurch's simulating electrochemical reactions with mathematica."
The function works normally but throws an error upon using @njit.
Error: "TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: convert make_function into JIT functions)
Cannot capture the non-constant value associated with variable 'x1' in a function that will escape." I have tried hard but could not pinpoint the source of the error or how to correct it. Thanks.

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import accumulate


@njit
def tridiag(x,y,z,b):

    x1 = np.concatenate(([0],np.array(x)))

    def a(previous, j):    
        return y[j]-x1[j]*z[j-1]/previous
    alpha = list(accumulate(range(1, len(b)), a, initial = y[0]))


    def eff(previous, j):
        return np.array((b[j]-x1[j]*previous)/alpha[j])
    f = list(accumulate(range(1, len(b)), eff, initial = b[0]/y[0]))


    def u(previous, j):
        return f[j]-z[j]*previous/alpha[j] 

    return np.array(list(accumulate(range(len(b)-2, -1, -1), u, initial = f[-1]))[::-1])
    
x = np.array([-1 for i in range(9)])
y = np.array([2 for i in range(10)])
z = np.array([-1 for i in range(9)])
b = np.array([1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1.5])

print(tridiag(x,y,z,b))
# expected answer: [ 5.04545455  9.09090909 12.13636364 14.18181818 15.22727273 
# 15.27272727 14.31818182 12.36363636  9.40909091  5.45454545]

#Error: ---------------
#~\anaconda3\envs\numerical\lib\site-packages\numba\core\dispatcher.py in _ 
#compile_for_args(self, *args, **kws)
#418                 e.patch_message(msg)
#419 
#--> 420             error_rewrite(e, 'typing')
#421         except errors.UnsupportedError as e:
#422             # Something unsupported is present in the user code, add help info

#~\anaconda3\envs\numerical\lib\site-packages\numba\core\dispatcher.py in error_rewrite(e, 
#issue_type)
#359                 raise e
#360             else:
#--> 361                 raise e.with_traceback(None)
#362 
#363         argtypes = []

#TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: convert make_function into JIT 
#functions)
#Cannot capture the non-constant value associated with variable 'x1' in a function that 
#will escape.

#File "<ipython-input-85-59a0d42c60e8>", line 24:

#def a(previous, j):
```

Comment: Please indent the code correctly or split the code and the error. Besides this, there is no way this code can work in Numba as it is. Firstly, AFAIK, closure are not supported. Then `itertools` is not supported either (especially `accumulate` with named arguments). To use Numba properly, you need to avoid closure, dynamic types, external unsupported modules (so almost all Python modules except Numpy and some Scipy functions), and most of named parameters.

Comment: I commented out the error. I understand dynamic  types and unsupported modules. But do you mean by closures? Meanwhile, I tried to replace the itertools.accumulate with a different function that does the same thing and still got the error.

Comment: Closures are functions that read variables from the context of the parent function and that can possibly modify them. Because implementing closure is tricky (and not much requested by numba users), it is not implemented by numba AFAIK. If you want to implement such functions, you need to move them away of the parent function and pass the variables using function parameters (and not implicit closure contexts). You should use the jit decorator on functions called by the parent function so that the full code will be jit compiled (and so efficient)

Comment: Thanks Jerome for your ideas. I rewrote the code and now it works really fast with @njit. The external library not recognized by Numba was the problem.